# How to get RSS token for BitBucket by PHP CLI?

Tags: php, rss, bitbucket

I want to get valid link `https://bitbucket.org/{username}/rss/feed?token={token}` (this is main problem) and then get valid response from this link in CLI.

I know my required parameters, e.g. `consumer_key, consumer_secret, request_token_url, authenticate_url, access_token_url`.

I tried to use `StudioIbizz\OAuth\OAuth1`, but is seems to be designed for Browser, not for CLI.

I tried to run:

```
$this->OAuth = new \StudioIbizz\OAuth\OAuth1($this->consumer_key,$this->consumer_secret);

$requestToken = $this->OAuth->getRequestToken($this->request_token_url,$this->authenticate_url);

$token = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
```

and paste this `$token` to my RSS link, but then I see message `You must have read access to access the RSS feed.` from Bitbucket.

I need Step by Step instructions for serious dummies.

---

Edit: I tried this:

```
$accessToken = $this->OAuth->getAccessToken($this->access_token_url,$requestToken['oauth_token_secret'],$requestToken['oauth_token']);
```

But then I get this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'StudioIbizz\OAuth\OAuthException' with message 'Unexpected HTTP status #400'
```

Comment: I couldn't find anything in Bitbucket docs about the token you should pass along the feed URL, but I'm sure the token given by the OAuth will not help you. I made some tries here and you need to be logged in even when giving a valid OAuth token. What kind of info you'd like to get from the feed? Maybe you can use specific API method to get that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any function related with that on official documentation. Maybe that feature not exists. 
For more information, you could use this link:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-bitbucket-cloud-rest-apis-222724129.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use stevenmaguire's [Bitbucket OAuth 2.0 support](https://github.com/stevenmaguire/oauth2-bitbucket) for the PHP League's [OAuth 2.0 Client](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client).

```
$provider = new Stevenmaguire\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Bitbucket([
    'clientId'          => '{bitbucket-client-id}',
    'clientSecret'      => '{bitbucket-client-secret}',
    'redirectUri'       => 'https://example.com/callback-url'
]);

$token = $_GET['code'];
```